# How do I do a subquery that displays -1 if the record is null

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT w.warehouse, 
       p.category, 
       p.product, 
      (select cr.min_stock 
       from critical cr 
       where cr.warehouse_id = w.id 
             and cr.product_id = p.id) as min_stock
FROM warehouse w, 
     product p
```

how do I make the min_stock display -1 if it is null.

Just to clarify, I can't use join, I need to make it in such a way that all products and warehouse would display min_stock even if no min_stock is defined.

suggested optimization would be appreciated.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use `JOIN`.  You want a `CROSS JOIN`, so you should be explicit about how you want to combine the two tables.  You can then follow the `CROSS JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT w.warehouse, p.category, p.product, 
       coalesce(cr.min_stock, -1) as min_stock 
FROM warehouse w cross join
     product p left join
     critical c
     on cr.warehouse_id = w.id and cr.product_id = p.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ifnull` function.

```
SELECT w.warehouse, 
       p.category, 
       p.product, 
      ifnull((select cr.min_stock 
       from critical cr 
       where cr.warehouse_id = w.id 
             and cr.product_id = p.id),0) as min_stock
FROM warehouse w, 
     product p
```

Hope this will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just batch update all of the values or make min_stock default to -1 when you create the SQL row. Here is what I would do:

`UPDATE critical SET min_stock = -1 WHERE min_stock = NULL;`